# Specify alternate location for language files based on incoming parameter

Tags: overrides, language

**Is there any way for me to feed an alternate/additional location to look for language files for a given incoming request?** I'd like to be able to give the hint from within a view.html.php file, but a system or other type of plugin would also be a another suitable alternative.

**Background**

As a word of explanation, I maintain a Joomla site with a component that offers a form of multi-tenanting. Periodically, I get asked by one tenant or another to change a label here or there on the site, but often times I can't do so without negative implications for other tenants. If I could capture language files for each tenant somehow, this would solve the issue for me. Each tenant typically has there own customised template, so it would be ideal to be able to capture the language files within the template directory structure.

To be clear, **I want to avoid creating template overrides** for this purpose though, as this just creates a maintenance nightmare. I've been down that road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Language files are just PHP .ini files. They can be anywhere, and you can load them manually.

Joomla manages the language files installation, default loading, overrides (language/overrides), and removal.

You can create the same organization from your extension, or add more files from a different location (JPATH_BASE), check how you can load specific files from a defined location with JLanguage::load. http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JLanguage.html#method_load